# wordpress get_post_meta not working in loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get posts on a page ordered by custom field "price" I have done the ordering but now I cannot get the value of 'price' echoed. The get_post_meta does not give any output. Here is the code:

```
$args=array(
'meta_key'=>'price',
'post_type' => 'page',
  'orderby'=>'meta_value_num',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1

);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
 $count=0;
  while ($count<4 && $my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

    <td><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <img alt="product" src="/product-images/image.jpg" height="100px" width="75px"/>
    <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
    <?php echo get_post_meta($my_query->ID, 'price', true); ?>
    </a>
    </td>
    <?php
    $count++;
  endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>
```

Comment: did you check that $my_query->ID is returning an int?

Comment: no it's not. What should I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're trying to use a property on `WP_Query` (`$ID`) instead of the current post's ID. The first argument of `get_post_meta` should be a post ID, not a property of `WP_Query`.

If this is somewhere in a template you can do this:

```
<?php
while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
    $my_query->the_post();

    // use the global $post object
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', true);
}
```

If it's no in a template file or somewhere that the global `$post` is declared, you can use `get_the_ID` instead:

```
<?php
while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
    $my_query->the_post();

    // use the global $post object
    echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'price', true);
}
```

Comment: tried both ways. Still no output at the get_post_meta statement. by the way. the_meta() is working and gives output. but not get_post_meta

Comment: Step one: make sure `get_the_ID` is returning something meaningful: `<?php var_dump(get_the_ID()); ?>` somewhere in your loop. What is it returning?

Comment: It returns ID of the post as int. ANOTHER UPDATE: only the 'price' custom field is not giving output. all other custom fields are showing.....

Comment: So the price custom field is empty. Or it's not getting saved in the admin area. Or you're using the wrong name.

Comment: Yep. i was using wrong name. it was Price not price. Thank You.